# python3 can't find newt library freebsd

Tags: python-3.x, freebsd

The newt library has been installed on freebsd 11

```
$ freebsd-version 
11.3-RELEASE-p6

$ pkg info | grep newt
newt-0.52.20_1                 Not Eriks Windowing Toolkit: console I/O handling library
```

python2.7 can find the library, but python3.6 can't find the library

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 23 2020, 02:13:26) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final 356365)] on freebsd11
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import snack
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snack'
>>> 
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 22 2020, 20:56:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final 356365)] on freebsd11
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import snack
>>>
```

I do not know much how the path processing works for pythonX.

Comment: `/devel/newt` builds and depends using python37. Check to make sure your version of `newt` is current.

Comment: @Rob , I added default_python variable in /etc/make.conf. then went to the newt port address and remove and install it again. The newt version was the latest version. seems when you use python 2.7 during installation, python3 can not find it and vis vers.

Comment: What version of FreeBSD are you using? What python versions do you have installed? Are your packages up to date?

Comment: Sorry, missed that you posted your FreeBSD version. I think your packages may be out of date. Have you tried running "pkg upgrade"?